# Can I use core-ajax and javascript in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer

I'm using google-signin for my login page so I want to use data receive from google account to handle core-ajax. But I can't use method .go() of core-ajax. Here is my example code. My button google-signin and core-ajax

```
<core-ajax
  id="ajax"
  handleAs="json"
  on-core-response="{{handleResponse}}"
  url=...>
</core-ajax>

<google-signin ... on-google-signin-success="{{handleSuccess}}"></google-signin>
```

And this's handleSuccess function:

```
Polymer({
...
   handleSuccess: function(){
            gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function(){
              var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
                'userId': 'me'
              });
              request.execute(function(resp) {
                console.log('Retrieved profile for: ' + resp.displayName);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(resp.emails[0].value));
                var ajax = document.getElementById('ajax');
                ajax.go();
              });
            });
          }
});
```

and `resp` is data response that I want to use for method 'POST' in core-ajax.
**My Question** is how I use `var ajax = document.getElementById('ajax')` to use ajax add method, headers, body, and go() function in my `handleSuccess` above and where exactly I can use it? Thanks for advice.

Comment: I just want to use `resp` outside request.execute() or `core-ajax` inside It. Does anyone have any ideas?